# Replace Hex String in File

Tags: c#, replace, hex, arrays, filestream

After banging my head on it for hours, I am at my wits end. I have a hex string in a file that is "68 39 30 00 00". The "39 30" is the decimal value "12345" which I am wanting to replace, and the "68" and "00 00" are just to ensure there is a single match.

I want to pass in a new decimal value such as "12346", and replace the existing value in the file. I have tried converting everything back and fourth between hex, byte arrays, and so on and feel it has to be much simpler than I am making it out to be.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Original Byte string to find and Replace "12345"
    byte[] original = new byte[] { 68, 39, 30, 00, 00 };

    int newPort = Convert.ToInt32("12346");
    string hexValue = newPort.ToString("X2");
    byte[] byteValue = StringToByteArray(hexValue);

    // Build Byte Array of the port to replace with. Starts with /x68 and ends with /x00/x00
    byte[] preByte = new byte[] { byte.Parse("68", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber) };
    byte[] portByte = byteValue;
    byte[] endByte = new byte[] { byte.Parse("00", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber), byte.Parse("00", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber) };

    byte[] replace = new byte[preByte.Length + portByte.Length + endByte.Length];

    preByte.CopyTo(replace, 0);
    portByte.CopyTo(replace, preByte.Length);
    endByte.CopyTo(replace, (preByte.Length + portByte.Length));

    Patch("Server.exe", "Server1.exe", original, replace);
}

static private byte[] StringToByteArray(string hex)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length)
                     .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                     .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
                     .ToArray();
}
```

Comment: So, are you saying your starting point is a **TEXT** file with the string literal "6839300000"?

Comment: It is an EXE file with a hardcoded value of "12345" which from the Hex Editor is "39 30", and "68 39 30 00 00" is the full hex string I am trying to search for and replace.

Comment: If you replace values in your EXE may very well not run because of various checksums etc. Also, an EXE is a binary file and not a string. Just because you can see it as a string it is not and will be stored as byte. So you would need to rewrite byte stream with just the correct data. can I ask **WHY** you are altering EXE files?!

Comment: It is an alpha release of a server application that currently has the port binding hard-coded. Changing the value via hex editor or alternative tools (i.e. the purpose of this) works fine until the feature is added at a later time. I just need to make my own to add command line control where other tools are GUI only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decimal value of **39 30**  is **14640** so it will check for the 14640 which is not present.

Hex value for **12345** is **30 39**. Just correct the values and your program will work fine.

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand. In the hex editor "12345" appears as "39 30" and the full string to replace is "68 39 30 00 00". This Python script does exactly the same thing, I am just trying to replicate it in C# https://gist.github.com/DonRevan/5958498

Comment: It is due to encoding and the way bytes are built up so they are often "flipped".

Comment: @BrettPowell just try by replacing the position of the array element. Lets see what you will get.

Comment: I was so fed up after all these hours I just wiped it and used a code snippet from elsewhere that worked fine. I will go ahead and accept your answer as I do believe it was correct. Thank you.

Comment: Your welcome. As @Belogix said it depends on what type of encoding you are editor is using.